# Retrieve file path during S3TransferManager.uploadDirectory

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to upload a directory with the new version of S3TransferManager v2 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html).

Everything works well except for the content type: I need to set the file content type according to the file name. For this reason, I thought to use the

```
UploadDirectoryRequest.Builder uploadFileRequestTransformer(Consumer<UploadFileRequest.Builder> uploadFileRequestTransformer)
```

But I don't know how can I retrieve the file path of the file that is going to be uploaded

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Inside the `uploadFileRequestTransformer` I can retrieve the file in this way

```
UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest = uploadFileRequestBuilder.build();

File file = uploadFileRequest.source().toFile();
```